# How to make an S3 lifecycle transition to the glacier if the last accessed object is more than 30 days old

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For my existing S3 bucket, I need to add glacier lifecycle, like moving objects from the standard class to the S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval storage class only if the object's last accessed date is more than 30 days old.
So the default life cycle works based on the object's created date, the accessed date, or the last modified date?

for me, it looks like life cycle working on created date or last modified date